# a script for downloading and merging

Tags: php, stream

i want to a script for downloading file . below example work well

```
<?php

if ( isset($_POST['downloadButton'] )) {

    $filename = ( isset($_POST["filename"]) ?
    $_POST["filename"] : null );


   if ( file_exists( $filename )) {

        header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=filename here");
        header("Content-Length: " . filesize( $filename) );
        header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate");
        readfile( $filename );
        exit;
     }
  }
?>
```

but i want download file chunk ! for example i download file and stop it in 4th byte and then download it from 5th byte to end and at the end merge it .
how can i do?

actually my Q is how to send this file from any byte that i want for example 5 to end or 3 to 10 or ...

Comment: You can only download one thing at a time, and there's no way to automatically merge. That will have to be done by the user.

Comment: yes i know it and mt Q isn't it . my Q is how to send this file from any byte that i want . for ex: 4 to 5 or 9 to end

Answer (score 1):

You can download a chunk of the file by reading the file into a variable and then writing a substring. So replace `readfile($filename);` with:

```
$contents = file_get_contents($filename);
echo substr($contents, $start, $length);
```

You'll also need to adjust the `Content-length:`:

```
header("Content-Length: " . min(filesize($filename)-$start, $length));
```

There's nothing you can do to automatically merge them. You can only download one file at a time, and the user will have to do that by hand after they download all the pieces.

Comment: But the OP also want to somehow marge it back after :|

Comment: @AlonEitan As I commented, there's no way to do that from PHP or the browser automatically. I've added it to the answer.

Comment: Well it's good enough for me, I hope the OP can finish the merging part themselves

Comment: He's edited the question to say that he's mainly just asking about how to do the partial download.

Comment: Oh, so now this the exact answer the the question :) Retracted my CV so it might not get closed

Comment: Why doesn't `substr()` work?